# flask basic authentication - custom htpasswd file

Tags: python, authentication, flask

I would like to use the [flask-htpasswd](https://github.com/carsongee/flask-htpasswd) but I need to authenticate against custom **htpasswd** file. My use case is that for specific **endpoint**, for instance http://localhost:5000/api/tenant it will look up the tenant's directory and authenticates using his **htpasswd** if there is one.

I am wondering how to perform that. I am not that deep into Python, tough currently digging into it.

Comment: I want to do the same, did you find a solution?

Comment: @honeymoon Yes, I did. If you want I can provide you with solution. I had to extend(inherit) one existing class to do that. Sorry for late comment on this.

Comment: This would be great, thanks a lot☺️

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to take what exists and adapt it to my specific use case (inherit in Python):

```
from flask_htpasswd import HtPasswdAuth
from passlib.apache import HtpasswdFile
from crypt import crypt
import logging
import os
import messages as msg
import settings
from functools import wraps

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)  # pylint: disable=invalid-name


class serviceHtPasswdAuth(HtPasswdAuth):
        def __init__(self, app):
            super().__init__(app)
            self.users = None

        def required(self, func):
            """
            Decorator function with basic and token authentication handler
            """
            @wraps(func)
            def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
                """
                Actual wrapper to run the auth checks.
                """
                # here an htpasswd file for that specific tenant id is read
                try:
                    self.users = HtpasswdFile(path=os.path.join(settings.TENANTS_DIRECTORY, kwargs['tenant_id'], 'htpasswd'))
                except(FileNotFoundError) as error:
                    log.error(msg.MISSING_TENANT_HTPASSWD_FILE)
                    return {"error": msg.MISSING_TENANT_HTPASSWD_FILE}, 404



                is_valid, user = self.authenticate()
                if not is_valid:
                    return self.auth_failed()
                kwargs['user'] = user

                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            return decorated
```